# Check Log in, email is in a different table to password. How?

Tags: php, authentication

I have a User table which has all the passwords, as well as a teacher stable which has the e-mail.

To log on they need to enter their e-mail and their password, currently I have the following, but not working :/

```
$sqlQuery="SELECT s.password, t.email, s.ID, t.ID 
    FROM user s, teacher t 
    WHERE t.email='$myEmail' AND s.password='$newPassword' AND s.ID = t.ID";
$result=mysql_query($sqlQuery);

//then it checks the row number etc, this part works. 
enter code here
```

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried reading up on JOIN?  That's almost certianly a better method.

Comment: @durbnpoisn the query is similar to join just the syntax is different.

Comment: I realize that.  I just think the JOIN is better.  Also, I notice that the way this is written, the ID is not being passed in.  So this won't retrieve a single record.  It will retrieve the entire list.

Comment: How do you mean the ID is not being parsed in? how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this
$sqlQuery="SELECT s.password, t.email, s.ID, t.ID 
    FROM user s, teacher t 
    WHERE t.email='".$myEmail."' AND s.password='".$newPassword."' AND s.ID = t.ID";
$result=mysql_query($sqlQuery);

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * 
    FROM user 
    INNER JOIN teacher
    WHERE user.email = '%s' AND user.password = '%s'",
        mysql_real_escape_string($email),
        mysql_real_escape_string($password)
);
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

This is tested, and working (Assuming you have the same ID in both tables for the user you want to get the info from

Comment: Nope, this is not working. 

I have this :
    $result = mysql_query($query);


    // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
    $rowNum=mysql_num_rows($result);
    echo "$rowNum";

and its not printing the row number at all now.. :/

Comment: Sorry i didnt test the code before i posted it.
See my updated answer, tested and working.

Comment: I don't have email in my user class. so i chaged 

user.email to tacher.email 

but it still is not working for me :/ 

maybe something wrong with my database? 

teacher table contains: ID and email
user table contains: ID,name, address, joindateand, and password

the id for techer and user are the same. 

mypassword also uses md5 enryption, maybe that is causing  a problem? :/

Comment: it seems to select all the records with the same password and correct e-mail address, however if people have the smae passwords it does not work. 

Even a peron with a password not similar to anyone else it doesn't work :/

Comment: When you use INNER JOIN it will merge all data from the teacher table to the user table. The password which, I assume, comes from a form input should be encrypted before querying. mysql_real_escape_string($password) should then be replaced with md5(mysql_real_escape_string($password))